# Office.context.mailbox.item is null

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have created an outlook add-in for our customers. For only one customer when we retrieve the Office.context.mailbox.item object, we are getting a null value. This issue only occurs for this customer and others have no issue.

Relevant code section:

```
    Office.onReady(function () {
Office.initialize = function () {}

       refresh: function () {
            try {
                app.logtext += "\nRefreshing data";
                if (!Office.initialize) {
                    app.logtext += "\nError initializing office..."
                } else {
                    if (Office.context) {
                        app.logtext += "\nOffice.context true"
                    }
                    if (Office.context.mailbox) {
                        app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox true"
                    }
                    if (Office.context.mailbox.item) {
                        app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item true"
                    }
                    app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId" + Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId;
                    
            } catch (err) {
                app.logtext += "\n JS error" + err;
            }
                          
        },

        }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);
    //UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox);
    app.logtext += "\Document is ready and task pane is loaded....";
});
```

});

// app.text is simply outputting the value.

Output:
Refreshing data
Office.context true
Office.context.mailbox true
Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId cannot find this value, since Office.context.mailbox.item is null.

Also, the issue is only in the outlook desktop version. OWA is working correctly..

Comment: Customer is using windows 7/windows 2019 with outlook version 2002.

Comment: Can you confirm this happen for messages which were never sent (compose)?

Comment: No this is happening for message in the inbox. Any message that is accessed in the read scenario